# Have working script, need to add variables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that works on my Google sheet.  When a value in column b is changed to the specified value the entire row is moved to another sheet.  I want to be able to specify multiple values that will all send the row to a certain sheet.  Bonus would be (if it's simple) to set up where 1 or more variables move the row to sheet 2, and 1 or more variables moves the row to sheet 3,

```
function onEdit() {
  // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

  var sheetNameToWatch = "2018";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 2; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "Next Year";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

(Credit: I didn't write this script, and can't remember where I found it)

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
var valueToWatch = "Next Year";
```

to

```
var valuesToWatch = ["Next Year", "Last year"] //add values to array
```

and

```
if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
```

to

```
if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && valuesToWatch.indexOf(range.getValue())>-1) {
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Awesome.  Does exactly what I hoped it would!  Thanks!